# fancybox ios6 support

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox_v2.1 & incorporated like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.fancylink").fancybox({
                autoDimensions: false,
                autoScale: true,
                width: '90%',
                height: 600,
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                type: 'iframe',
                modal: false,
                marginTop: 20,
                closeBtn : true,
                fitToView   : false,
                autoSize    : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                centerOnScroll: true
            });
        });
```

I am facing weird issue, text is not visible properly in between lines after given height, it looks like there is some white box above text in ios5 but in ios6 it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **type: 'ajax'** in place of **type: 'iframe'** and now it supports on both ios6 & ios5

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: well, it all depends on the type of content you are trying to open (you never posted your html). This solution may be specific to your case but not necessarily a rule of the thumb.